# Как PyQt приложение перенести на андроид или переделать в Kivy?

Tags: python, pyqt5, kivy

Можно ли PyQt приложение запустить на андроид? Или его как-нибудь переделать в киви?

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически, с помощью какой-либо утилиты - никак, ибо таких не существует. Вручную - вполне. Ищите специалиста по Kivy. Если интересное приложение - стучите в личку.

Comment: Pyqtdeploy отрыскал. Говорят, что с версии 0.5 можно портировать PyQt на андроид

Comment: Тю, блин, я думал, переписать....

Comment: https://m.vk.com/wall-99411738_1199 - сюда посмотрите. Обратите внимание, что это приложение способно запускать на устройстве код, написанный на PyQt5.